# My JQuery Plugin Appends "0" to the body element

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, popupwindow, thickbox

I created a small JQuery Plugin and I'm using thickbox for popups.
I don't know where it came from but I have a "0" appended to the end of the `body` element.
I suspect that one of those outputs a success indicator maybe?

Is anyone familiar with this behavior?

Edit:

PHP

```
add_action('wp_ajax_product_picker', 'popup_content');
function popup_content() {
    iframe_header();
    echo 'aaa';
    iframe_footer();
}
```

JS

```
var currentPicker = {};

(function ($) {

    $.fn.pick_product = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            callback: function(){}
            }, options);
        this.on('click',function () {
            var url = product_picker.ajax_url + "?action=product_picker&TB_iframe=true&width=600&height=550";
            tb_show("My Caption", url);
        });
    return this;
    };
}(jQuery));

jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#test-product-picker').pick_product({
        callback: function (variation_id, size) {
            alert('aaa');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your code.

Comment: Remove the 0 from your plugin code.

Comment: So where is your plugin code?

Comment: When WP Ajax returns 0 it means that he didn't find the function. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

Comment: I already got the answer thanks to Adeel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using it on the front end of your site you have to use the

`wp_ajax_nopriv_product_picker` and also place `die()` after your function.

`function popup_content() {
    iframe_header();
    echo 'aaa';
    iframe_footer();
    die();
}`

Comment: Thank you very much i needed the die() function. It was that simple.